# hbm2ddl : on delete set null issue

Tags: java, hibernate, database-schema, hbm2ddl

I am generating schema using hibernate hbm2ddl feature..
while defining Realtionship between entities, I want to set ON DELETE SET NULL for child class.
But hibernate does not allow us to define such  constraint annotationally.
I want to define this annotation. 
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [5.6. Auxiliary Database Objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-database-object) in the NHibernate reference. You can write an ALTER command tweak the constraint as needed.

Comment: thanks for replying Oskar..! The link you have given seem to be helping for .NET framework.. But I am using Java annnotation. It would be better if u post some code so that i will map it with my needs.. awaiting reply...

Comment: @ShreyasDeshpande if you are using Java Hibernate, why did you use NHibernate tags? Also, what Oskar wrote applies to Hibernate as well, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-database-object